# Control is lost after changing build action to release instead of debug

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, build, release

My problem is: when I set the project build action to release instead of debug a control from an external library is lost. every line that uses it have this error:

> 'myControlName' is not defined.

the control is part of SDK library (I mean I didn't create it)
when I set the action to debug again and rebuild the problem is gone
so what's the problem?

Edit: I have encountered this problem before when i used [WeifenLuo DockPanel Suite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s542v.png)

now it's another library but the error is the same

Edit: the reference is a dll file
screenshot after setting build action to release.
[image]

Comment: unbelievable, no answers, no comments, no votes, even the views aren't good, like the whole question does not exist!! please any clue, any point i can begin with, i have no idea what to research.

Comment: Very little to go on. Am I correct that 'myControlname' is a variablename that 'suddenly' isn't defined or is it about a missing type? Can you show some lines of code where the errors is generated for

Comment: @Eddy you got it , the reason i didn't add code because it's not a language specific issue.

Comment: perhaps not language specific but the screenshot shows us that it is in fact a type (from a reference dll) that is missing which makes a lot more sense than that a variable declaration would go missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are project settings that are specific to the configuration, they store different values for Debug vs Release.  The very first thing you'll have to fix, visible in the screen shot, is Project + Properties, Compile tab, scroll down, Advanced Compile Options, Target CPU.  Change it from AnyCPU to x86.  An ActiveX control like you are using is very rarely available in 64-bit mode, you have to force the app to run in 32-bit mode so it can use the control.

That however is a long short for the specific error.  Another one that's important and more readily explains such a problem is the Framework Target setting.  Try selecting the full one instead of the Client profile.  Not a great explanation either btw.  Chase possible other fixes by comparing the Compile tab settings for the Debug vs Release configurations.  A complete outlier explanation is that you added the ActiveX reference by editing the .vbproj file instead of using the IDE.  Be sure to pay attention to any warnings in the Error List window, such a warning may produce hard to diagnose other errors.

Comment: this worked on the old project, i did everything you said, but i don't know which part of it fixed the problem,
any way i will test it on the new project once i get to my office, it should be OK, thanks

Comment: the second project i had a different story, but as you said, chasing after warnings i found this:"Could not resolve this reference". i fixed that and it's alright

Comment: Yup, that was the one.  Very common to overlook that warning btw.

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing the control? Is it in a directory within your solution?

Try right clicking on the source dll within the project, then select 'Properties'. the 'Copy to Output Directory' should be 'Copy Always'.

Comment: references don't have this choice.